# Update Update-Site From Maven Repository

Tags: tycho

I have a normal Eclipse plug-in build with Tycho, and want to build an update site with the very same Tycho. My problem is figuring out how to get the artifact from its Maven GAVs (or optionally the JAR) into the update site.

What I tried:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-p2-extras-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-to-update-site</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>mirror</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>
                            <repository>
                                <url>${project.baseUri}/target/repository</url>
                            </repository>
                        </source>
                        <destination>${project.basedir}</destination>
                        <append>true</append>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This takes the repository from *target/repository* and merges it with the one in the base directory of the project. So every plug-in in *target/repository* will be added to the update site.

This works with a target platform file, but of course not with Maven GAVs or JAR. I tried adding the plug-in as a dependency and using `dependency:copy-dependencies`, but this will not create a P2 repository.

There is the plug-in [tycho-p2-repository:assemble-repository](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-p2/tycho-p2-repository-plugin/assemble-repository-mojo.html), but I'm not sure it can help me create a P2 repository for `tycho-p2-extras-plugin` to consume. Or even as standalone.

I found [reficio's p2-maven-plugin](https://github.com/reficio/p2-maven-plugin), which can generate P2 repositories from JARs, but it doesn't support Tycho at all.

I feel like I'm only one step away from a solution. So how do I build a P2 repository from Maven GAVs (or JAR files)?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible with Tycho. So I used the command line:

```
SET ECLIPSE_HOME=S:/Development/Eclipse 2018-12
SET EQUINOX_VERSION=1.5.200.v20180922-1751
SET CURRENT_PATH=%~dp0
SET SOURCE_REPOSITORY=%CURRENT_PATH%\dropin
SET TARGET_REPOSITORY=%CURRENT_PATH%\


java -jar "%ECLIPSE_HOME%/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_%EQUINOX_VERSION%.jar" 
    -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher 
    -metadataRepository "file:/%TARGET_REPOSITORY%" -artifactRepository "file:/%TARGET_REPOSITORY%" 
    -source "%SOURCE_REPOSITORY%" -publishArtifacts -append
```

However I haven't been able to create categories, so the repository appears to be empty on default.